# How to remove Db2 encryption password in current connection

Tags: encryption, db2

Db2 allows to set a password in the connection using

```
SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD 'mysecretpw'
```

This avoids having to set the password on each ENCRYPT() / DECRYPT() usage.

However, how can I remove the password after I finished my work so that other parts of code that work with the same connection are not able to use my password ?

- I didn't find a 'REMOVE/DROP ENCRYPTION PASSWORD'.
- Setting the password to an empty string `SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD ''`caused problems when my code was invoked multiple times in the same process: the second invocation got 'NO PASSWORD SET' SQL20143N / SQLSTATE 51039 even though it did set the correct password again using "SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD 'mysecretpw'" again before using ENCRYPT/DECRYPT ... Db2 also says that you have to specify a password between 6 and 127 bytes ...
- Setting an arbitrary string as new password (e.g. blanks) is also not ideal, as this does not allow Db2 to detect 'no password set' conditions so that you don't realize that you are encrypting / decrypting with a wrong password ...

So how to clear the password correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Db2 LUW documentation (at version 11.1) for `SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD` does not state it explicitly but the product allows you to set the password to an empty string with the result that subsequent encrypt/decrypt actions in that connection will return -20143 sqlcode. When I test this behaviour with the CLP it behaves as expected on Db2 LUW.

So while both Db2 for Z/OS and Db2 for i-series for `SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD` explicitly mention the empty string behaviour for the password (and the Db2 LUW knowledge center does not), it appears all three code bases have the same behaviour as regards the consequence of setting the password to the empty string.

If you have a testcase that proves you get an -20143 sqlcode even after using `SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD` to a valid good password, then perhaps you should publish that testcase or open a PMR with IBM.  If your code is multi threaded , you may get unexpected results as the password is in special register and changing it is not under transaction control, so there may be timing issues.

Removing the password seems to be possible either via disconnecting the session or setting it to an empty string in a single-connection scenario, and with the CLP the product appears to behave as expected for me when I set the password to an empty string, and subsequently set it to a valid password for the same connection.

Comment: A colleague made me aware of the Db2 z/OS documentation: [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_setencryptionpassword.html) which states: "... must be between 6 and 127 inclusive or must be an empty string. If an empty string is specified, the default encryption password is set to no value." So it seems to be possible, at least on Db2 z/OS ?

Comment: DB2 for i documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzsetep.htm has the same declaration.

Comment: The 'edited' version of the answer is correct. `SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD ''` removes the password. The problem I mentioned in the question only occurs when the password is set in a client (either JDBC or ODBC) and the ENCRYPT/DECRYPT calls are done in a stored procedure called by a trigger, so a very special case. For that problem I opened a PMR ...

Comment: Those details omitted from your question , re calling the stored procedure from a trigger. In what language is the stored procedure written?  And on which operating-system does the stored-procedure run?

Comment: @mao: didn't notice in the beginning that my specific scenario causes the trouble. It's an SQL procedure. The scenario works on z/OS, but fails on xLinux, AIX and Windows. Looks like setting the password initially is noticed by the procedure, as well as the reset. But setting the password for the second insert will no longer propagate to the procedure. I tried to put the procedure code into the trigger directly and there it seems to work, but this does not fit to my real scenario ...